# Add multiple people to chatter group and NOT email notify them

Tags: chatter

I want to bulk add all my users to an ALL Company Chatter group, but i do not want to send out  email notifications.

I know i can add people in bulk with DemandTools, I just do not want emails to go out to everyone. I just want to add them.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** The `UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail` field of the `User` object only affects the generic Salesforce chatter. It may be required that you toggle the `UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail` field of the `NetworkMember` record aswell. The `NetworkMember` relationship is also used in Communities Chatter.

The suggested answer does not work. There is no way to disable the sending of this notification using permissions or even DMLOptions. There is currently an IdeaExchange post to request a solution for this scenario, giving the administrator the ability to disable these notifications.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000sZB2AAM

And not enough REP to post a comment.

Answer (score 2):

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176780&language=en_US

as explained in the article, you need to first disable all user's chatter emails via the UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail column, do your CollaborationGroupMember inserts, then revert the users original preferences.

The `UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail` field of the `User` object only affects the generic Salesforce chatter. It may be required that you toggle the `UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail` field of the `NetworkMember` record aswell. The `NetworkMember` relationship is also used in Communities Chatter.

Comment: donjay, were you actually able to get this to work? I have tried this and it doesn't appear to impact emails that go out when a user joins a group.